# PHP Contact Form - Reply to email form

Tags: php, forms, email

I created a contact form that uses my php script to email the form:

```
    <?php

$header = 'From: info@omgphotobooth.com.ar' . "\r\n" .
'Reply-To: '.$POST["email"]. "\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

$msg = '';

foreach($_POST as $k => $v) {
    $msg .= "$k: $v \n";
}

$res = @mail('maia@jonetsugroup.com.ar', 'Contacto desde web', $msg, $header);

header('Content-type: text/json');


$res = true;

echo json_encode( array('result' => $res) );

?>
```

I receive the email on my account just fine, but then I want to reply to the "email" directions that the user wrote into the form. How can I do that?

Comment: What goes wrong with the code you supplied?

Comment: `'Reply-To: '.$POST["email"]"\r\n" .` What's going on in that line? Did you miss a concatenation between `"]` and `"\r`?

Comment: I just correct it. Its okay but when I receive the email in my account and I select "reply" to the email I want to response to the email that the user complete on the form, instead, it reply to "info@omgphotobooth.com.ar". If the user complete the form with the email info@www.com.ar, I want to response that email directly to that address. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$header = 'From: info@omgphotobooth.com.ar' . "\r\n" .
'Reply-To: '.$_POST["email"].'.\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
```

Comment: How about `$_POST["email"]`?